# Android bypassing CouchDB authentication

Tags: android, couchdb

I am using CouchDB to authenticate users for my app, which is essentially just a front end for a CouchDB database, so I am using the API to authenticate users, logically, this code

```
httpget(http://wrongusername:wrongpassword@mycouch.com:5984) //not my actual code
```

should come back with the response

```
{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"Name or password is incorrect."}
```

as it does when I `cURL` the same URL. But instead, no matter what I put in as the username and password it returns

```
{"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"1.2.0"}
```

And I know I'm not somehow storing a valid URI or that response in the code because I've changed the parameters of HttpGET to return _all_docs, and it has returned all the documents, which a normal user shouldn't be able to to do. I have not modified any of the configuration files and the login is not stored anywhere in the database

Comment: The url looks malformed. `5984` is couchdb's standard port. With the url above, you'd hit a database called 5984 on a couchdb running on port 80.

Comment: @skiqh that was a typo, i fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are hitting the same CouchDB instance that you have set up the users with? Clients, not even Android, have a way of bypassing authentication.

Comment: I am absolutely positive its the same instance, and I yes, I realize there should be no way for it to bypass authentication, hence this question

Comment: CouchDB actually dines wrong credentials even when no user is set up, so this can’t really happen without a gross misconfiguration, or somehow that password you are using is correct regardless of what you think it is :)

Comment: @lehnhardt ok, lets assume its "gross misconfiguration" what mistake might I have made? HOW, could this occur?

Comment: e.g. changing the authentication_handlers config setting, or using any custom auth handlers that have not been tested properly.

Comment: What do you get when you do this on the command line: `curl http://user:pass@host`? (fill in user & pass, and then use a wrong pass)

Comment: I have not modified any of the config files, and when I `curl` the correct login it returns `couchdb:welcome` and incorrect it returns `error:unauthorized`

Comment: Then I’d say the issues is with the library that you use to talk to CouchDB. Maybe there is some inadvertent caching going on? Or it sends credentials that are different from what you specify. You can set the CouchDB log level to debug and see its log for what requests end up at CouchDB.

Comment: I checked the logs, the request does not contain any sort of information that would clear authentication

Answer (score -1):

Couchdb uses session cookies for authentication, maybe your http client authorized to couchdb before and keeps the cookie around?

Another thing I can think of: unless you set `require_valid_user` to `true`, couchdb only restricts access to individual databases, which would explain the "welcome" message on `/`.

Comment: CouchDB can use basic auth just fine.

Comment: Yes, I actually checked this